# Ng-options selecting value as a int instead of a string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options

I have an array of objects

```
usage: [{label: 'Main', value: '30' },{ label: 'Second', value: '27' },{ label: 'Third', value: '50' }];
```

This is how I use the ng-options

```
<select class="Input" ng-model="myCtrl.data.usages" ng-options="usage.value as usage.label  for usage in myCtrl.data.usages">
```

It seems to work as it selects the right value.. However it selects as a string. Is there a way to make it select / parse as integer? So instead of `'27'`, it will save as `27`

Comment: You can just parse it while selecting. So in your controller `$scope.selectValue = +myCtrl.data.usages`;

Comment: notice the `+` sign before `myCtrl.data.usages` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for this. This will allow you to parse and manipulate the value however you wish. Observe the following example...

```
app.filter('num', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return parseInt(input, 10);
    };
});
```

---

```
<select 
    ng-options="(usage.value | num) as usage.label  for usage in myCtrl.data.usages">
</select>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ga392sn2/) - demo